# OpenCV Mat corruption

Tags: c++, opencv, networking, zeromq

I have been working on a simple video-over-ip program, partly for use in a project and partly to teach myself some basics of networking using high-level interfaces. The trouble is that I can send the data from a `cv::Mat` over the network just fine, but once I attempt to decode the data, it appears to be missing much of the color data.  The code is in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/PyroAVR/789cc08c78e53d5ed8ddce3a024a9b2e), which contains all the files necessary to build and run the project under Linux. Can anyone shine some light on this?

If you need any more information, let me know. You'll need a webcam to test, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you copy your data with `memcpy(m.data(), frame.data, frame.rows * frame.cols);`, you're only copying a third of the total data since your image is a 3-channel one.

Try to change it to `memcpy(m.data(), frame.data, 3 * frame.rows * frame.cols);` (and allocate enough space before).

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the problem, sure enough the color data was only partially copied to the client.  I did get it to work with only your changes, and color was displayed, but skewed.  Removing `vmetadata.cvstep` from the `Mat` constructor in the client then showed the correct image.